# How could I detect this object / form the best way?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, object-detection

I am new to image processing and opencv and was wondering what the best way to detect such forms would be:

[image]

The object can have varying color.
Some sort of SURF feature detection, or is there a more simple solution?

Comment: You could look into Blob Detection... It would be helpful if you provided some more concrete real world examples or provide more descriptive info of what you are trying to accomplish (do all "forms" look exactly like the one shown?).

Comment: Yes, all forms look the same. Bit like an ant body. The ends are thicker than the center, so not a real rectangle..

Comment: Are the images always this clean?

Comment: If it where me I would try to detect the object via a Haar Cascade: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html (unfortunately doing this isn't a small task..)

Comment: I am doing a contrast adjustment so the image has a better destinction between for -and background.